# Unable to play videos in Firefox

Tags: 12.04, firefox, flash, firefox-extensions

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I try to open a video in Firefox 25 browser, it is showing like install flash media plugin. When I click the button "install plugin" it is not installing.

Please help on with this one. I am having this problem since the last 5 days.

Answer (score 4):

Open your Terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```